# Compare 2 Excel data if same column name having different postion

Tags: java

I want to compare two excel sheet data with same column name, excel sheet having same column name but position of column name will be different. So, I need logic first check column name and compare data

below code is working if both the sheet column name have same position or index.

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    // Workbook1 Code
    
    FileInputStream filepath1 = new FileInputStream(".\\DataFile\\Book1.xlsx");

    XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(filepath1);

    XSSFSheet worksheet1 = workbook1.getSheet("sheet1");

    int rowcount1 = worksheet1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    int CellCount=worksheet1.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();


    System.out.println("row count of worbook1:" + rowcount1);

    // Workbook2 Code

    FileInputStream filepath2 = new FileInputStream(".\\DataFile\\Book2.xlsx");

    XSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new XSSFWorkbook(filepath2);

    XSSFSheet worksheet2 = workbook2.getSheet("sheet1");

    int rowcount2 = worksheet2.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    System.out.println("row count of worbook2:" + rowcount2);

    if (rowcount1 == rowcount2) // condition if rowcount1 is equal to row count of worbook2 are same
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount1; i++) {
            
            for(int j=0; j<CellCount; j++)
            {
                
            XSSFCell row1 = worksheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j);

            XSSFCell row2 = worksheet2.getRow(i).getCell(j);
            
            row1.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
            
            String cellvalue=row1.getStringCellValue();
            
            row2.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
            
            String cellvalue2=row2.getStringCellValue();
            
            if(!cellvalue.equals(cellvalue2))
            {
                System.out.println("Row number:"+i+ "  Column number:"+j+" [ERROR] :" + "Diference in data " +"| Book1 id = " + cellvalue + " | Book2 id = " + cellvalue2);
            }
            
            }}}
```

Comment: [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You dropped some code, and some requirements, but what is your question?